# Wordpress change homepage link (htaccess) (index)

Tags: ftp, links, homepage

Currently I'm creating content for a website. I noticed that in the homepage extension, there was 'homepage' added to the homepage link:
www.charlottes-haarmode.nl/homepage

When I tried to remove the 'homepage' behind the link in WordPress (General Settings, see picture). The page went down to a 404. If I also changed the Wordpress address, I couldn't even get into Wordpress anymore (I got that problem solved by going into FTP). 
[Before adjustment in general settings WP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVLDO.png)
[After adjustment in general settings WP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJAuj.png)

I also tried to add code (UPDATE ETC.) in FTP files, also tried on the host server but nothing seems to work. Now I dug a little deeper into the code of the htaccess and index files and ran into this (see pictures). I suspect something isn't right here with a 301 and several files that are named htaccess and index. Does anybody have an idea where I can replace/remove certain files or code to remove the 'homepage' behind the site address?
[htaccess file inside homepage folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUia9.png)
[htaccess file outside homepage folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnU5b.png)
[index file inside homepage folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV4M7.png)
[index file outside homepage folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufbZQ.png)

Comment: Questions about WordPress are specifically out of scope here at Super User

Comment: From your files it sounds like you installed WordPress inside that `homepage` folder. It is possible but very tricky to set WordPress up to think it's in a higher-up folder. I would recommend moving all your files up into the root folder (`www.charlottes-haarmode.nl`) and deleting everything from the database. Then you can reinstall WordPress directly in the root and the homepage will be right at that URL.